# Compiler Warnings with Mailgun/AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking, compiler-warnings, mailgun

I have some compiler warnings in my app which I do not understand:

[image]

I have installed Mailgun and AFNetworking using cocoapods. My main project has SystemConfiguration and MobileCoreServices frameworks imported however I still get these issues.

These warnings are unnecessary and my app works perfectly regardless!

How would I go about removing these?

Comment: I guess these issue are related to the implementation of the framework with the current iOS SDK (Especially with `deprecated` method or these kind of things). For more information you could open request in the repository of talked framework (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking and https://github.com/rackerlabs/objc-mailgun)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFNetworking required to link `SystemConfiguration.framework` and `MobileCoreService.framework` and import them in you *.pch file. 
To do that, go into your target's settings -> Build Phases tab -> Link Binary With Libraries
Click on "+" button and choose those two frameworks (SystemConfiguration and MobileCoreService). 
After, open your [Project name]-Prefix.pch file (by default its in `Supporting Files` group folder) and add

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

**IMNPORTANT NOTE**
In case if you installed from pods, then you must import those also in 2 places:
1. Pods->AFNetworking->Supporting Files->Pods-AFNetworking-prefix.pch
2. Pods->maligun->Supporting Files->Pods-mailgun-prefix

[image]

Answer (score 3):

AFNetworking library wantedly kept `#Warning` flag for showing the warning. That you need not worry about. Still you want to suppress warning go to your project build phase > Compile sources > click on File that's showing warning > add `-w` to it. Now build your application. But in general we don't need to worry about warning that are there in library.

Answer (score 3):

Please note suppressing warnings is not a good practice,
Just linking frameworks, will not help, you need to import them in `<project>.pch file`
  (Please note: not all in all Pod dependencies!, only in your project's `pch` file)
Here is a small guide to resolve this issue!

1) Open your `<project>.pch file` (that's the precompiled header file)
2) Make sure you have imported the frameworks

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

[image]